# How do you view data from Azure's easy tables and view it in a list view?

Tags: java, android, azure

Hi i seem to be forever looking for an example of how to insert and retrieve data from Azure. I have managed to insert data into the azure easy table (happy days).I want to know how to retrieve that data and display it in a list view or even an alertDialog builder for all i care just need a way to view the data in my app.
 using the code below i have managed to enter some data into the azure database.

```
public void saveToAzure(){
    button_save_to_azure = (Button)findViewById(R.id.btnSaveDataToAzure);
    button_save_to_azure.setOnClickListener(
            new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    myAzuretbl.SEEDNAME = edittext_seed_name_for_azure.getText().toString();
                    mClient.getTable(Azuretbl.class).insert(myAzuretbl, new TableOperationCallback<Azuretbl>() {
                        @Override
                        public void onCompleted(Azuretbl entity, Exception exception, ServiceFilterResponse response) {
                            if (exception == null) {
                                // Insert succeeded
                                Toast myToast = Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Inserted", Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
                                myToast.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER_HORIZONTAL|Gravity.CENTER_VERTICAL,0,0);
                                myToast.show();

                                edittext_seed_name_for_azure.setText("");

                            } else {
                                // Insert failed

                                Toast myFailToast = Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Not Inserted", Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
                                myFailToast.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER_HORIZONTAL|Gravity.CENTER_VERTICAL,0,0);
                                myFailToast.show();

                                edittext_seed_name_for_azure.setText("");
                            }
                        }
                    });

                }
            }
    );
}
```

At the moment i can enter 1 field into the database and i know how to enter more. I would like to now retrieve this data.
my local azure table looks like this at the moment:

```
package com.jonnyg.gardenapp;


public class Azuretbl {
    public String Id;
    public String SEEDNAME;
}
```

nothing special but it does the job.
I have looked at the documentation and none of it makes sense to me.looking at the new quick start guide and then looking at the documentation are completely different.
from the way i am doing it here is there a follow up in retriving the data and viewing it in either a list view or alertDialog builder?.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@JonnyG,
Could you please try to use the `excute()` method and  refer to SDK document (https://github.com/Azure/azure-mobile-services/blob/master/sdk/android/src/sdk/src/main/java/com/microsoft/windowsazure/mobileservices/table/MobileServiceTable.java )?

Generally, we can retrieve the table rows as following:

```
MobileServiceList<Azuretbl> result =mClient.getTable(Azuretbl.class).execute().get(); 
for(Azuretbl item:result)
{
//your code
}
```

Also, you can check this official document sample(https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/mobile-services-android-how-to-use-client-library/#querying)
Hope this helps.

Comment: Hi Will Shao i have made some improvements to my project. i can view data in the logcat from azure but the problem in that i get null back when i look for the Name. Do i edit my 1st question and add the code or how do i explain this further im new to stackOverflow. Thanks

Comment: @JonnyG, Do you want to query the result by 'Name' field? If you database have this column, you can search it in your query function:.mClient.getTable(Azuretbl.class).where().field("Name").eq("something").execute().get(); Please see this document:https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/mobile-services-android-how-to-use-client-library/#querying

Comment: Nice. Seems that you have resolved this issue.http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36516834/azure-easy-table-given-me-package-info-in-my-listview-instead-of-data-in-the-azu