# Azure easy table given me package info in my ListView instead of data in the Azure table

Tags: java, android, listview, azure

When i query the azure table for a SEEDNAME (column in my Azure table) i get null back. when i put required data in the logcat like: Log.i(TAG, "Read object with ID " + item.id + " " + item.SEEDNAME); i get the proper ID  and a null for the name.
and when i add the data to a list view i get what looks like the package name.

```
public class Azuretbl {

public String id;
public String SEEDNAME;
public  String SEEDTYPE;
public int SEED_AMOUNT;
```

}
This is the client table which matches table on Azure.

the Code for querying:

```
public void viewFromAzure(){
    button_view_from_azure = (Button)findViewById(R.id.btnViewDataFromAzure);
    button_view_from_azure.setOnClickListener(
            new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    final ArrayAdapter<Azuretbl> myAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<Azuretbl>
                            (getApplicationContext(), android.R.layout.simple_list_item_activated_1);

                    azure_list_view = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listViewAzure);

                    azure_list_view.setAdapter(myAdapter);

                    new AsyncTask<Void, Void, MobileServiceList<Azuretbl>>(){
                        MobileServiceTable<Azuretbl> myTestAzuretbl = mClient.getTable(Azuretbl.class);

                        @Override
                        protected MobileServiceList<Azuretbl> doInBackground(Void... params) {
                            MobileServiceList<Azuretbl> result;
                            try {
                                result = myTestAzuretbl.where().field("SEEDNAME").eq("Tomato").execute().get();

                                /*where().field("SEEDNAME").eq("tomato").*/
                                final MobileServiceList<Azuretbl> finalResult = result;
                                runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                                    @Override
                                    public void run() {

                                    myAdapter.clear();

                                        for (Azuretbl item : finalResult) {

                                            Log.i(TAG, "Read object with ID " + item.id + " " + item.SEEDNAME);

                                            System.out.println("Item is " + finalResult);
                                            myAdapter.add(item);
                                        }
                                    }
                                });

                            } catch (Exception exception) {

                            }
                            return null;
                        }
                    }.execute();


                }
            }
    );
}
```

and i get this in the logcat:

```
04-09 13:21:29.232 3029-3029/? I/JonnysMessage: Read object with ID a822b906-5f84-4345-86d2-3031247e380a null

04-09 13:21:29.232 3029-3029/? I/System.out: Item is [com.jonnyg.gardenapp.Azuretbl@537e457c, com.jonnyg.gardenapp.Azuretbl@537e4b04]
```

Snapshot of listview on app
[Result of the listview on app](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3YMUO.png)

snapshot of Azure table on cloud
[Azure snapshot of table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ECe0N.png)

just to add i am using the new portal on azure. i have permission set for read insert etc.. to allow anonymous access. I am not using an application key do i need one?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have figured out my problem.
On azure the easy table i had created had the field SEEDNAME as seedNAME in the area where you add a column this was visible and not visible when viewing the table on azure. After solving this the Seed name was viewing in the logcat.

I also created a custom adapter to view the data in a listview.